# Integer Textbox Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, textbox, integer, label

So I'm new to coding and I'm trying to make a label display a result based on what number is in a textbox. The number in the textbox is based on what button a person clicks. I want to the label to read different values if the textbox is above or below certain numbers, the code I have doesn't work, any help please guys?

```
 Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click, btn2.Click, btn3.Click, btn4.Click, btn5.Click, btn6.Click, btn7.Click, btn8.Click, btn9.Click, btn10.Click, _
    btn11.Click, btn12.Click, btn13.Click, btn14.Click, btn15.Click, btn16.Click, btn17.Click, btn18.Click, btn19.Click, btn20.Click, btn21.Click, btn22.Click, btn23.Click, btn24.Click, btn25.Click, btn26.Click, _
    btn27.Click, btn28.Click, btn29.Click, btn30.Click, btn31.Click, btn32.Click, btn33.Click, btn34.Click, btn35.Click, btn36.Click, btn37.Click, btn38.Click, btn39.Click, btn40.Click, btn41.Click, btn42.Click, _
    btn43.Click, btn44.Click, btn45.Click, btn46.Click, btn47.Click, btn48.Click, btn49.Click, btn50.Click, btn51.Click, btn52.Click, btn53.Click, btn54.Click, btn55.Click, btn56.Click, btn57.Click, btn58.Click, _
    btn59.Click, btn60.Click, btn61.Click, btn62.Click, btn63.Click, btn64.Click, btn65.Click, btn66.Click, btn67.Click, btn68.Click, btn69.Click, btn70.Click, btn71.Click, btn72.Click, btn73.Click, btn74.Click, _
    btn75.Click, btn76.Click, btn77.Click, btn78.Click, btn79.Click, btn80.Click, btn81.Click, btn82.Click, btn83.Click, btn84.Click, btn85.Click, btn86.Click, btn87.Click, btn88.Click, btn89.Click, btn90.Click, _
    btn91.Click, btn92.Click, btn93.Click, btn94.Click, btn95.Click, btn96.Click, btn97.Click, btn98.Click, btn99.Click, btn100.Click, btn101.Click, btn102.Click, btn103.Click, btn104.Click, btn105.Click, btn106.Click, _
    btn107.Click, btn108.Click, btn109.Click, btn110.Click, btn111.Click, btn112.Click, btn113.Click, btn114.Click, btn115.Click, btn116.Click, btn117.Click, btn118.Click, btn119.Click, btn110.Click, btn111.Click, btn112.Click, _
    btn113.Click, btn114.Click, btn115.Click, btn116.Click, btn117.Click, btn118.Click, btn119.Click, btn120.Click, btn121.Click, btn122.Click, btn123.Click, btn124.Click, btn125.Click, btn126.Click, btn127.Click, btn128.Click, _
    btn129.Click, btn130.Click, btn131.Click, btn132.Click, btn133.Click, btn134.Click, btn135.Click, btn136.Click, btn137.Click, btn138.Click, btn139.Click, btn140.Click, btn141.Click, btn142.Click, btn143.Click, btn144.Click, _
    btn145.Click, btn146.Click, btn147.Click, btn148.Click, btn149.Click, btn150.Click, btn151.Click, btn152.Click, btn153.Click, btn154.Click, btn155.Click, btn156.Click, btn157.Click, btn158.Click, btn159.Click, btn160.Click, _
    btn161.Click, btn162.Click, btn163.Click, btn164.Click, btn165.Click, btn166.Click, btn167.Click, btn168.Click, btn169.Click, btn170.Click, btn171.Click, btn172.Click, btn173.Click, btn174.Click, btn175.Click, btn176.Click, _
    btn177.Click, btn178.Click, btn179.Click, btn180.Click, btn181.Click, btn182.Click, btn183.Click, btn184.Click, btn185.Click, btn186.Click, btn187.Click, btn188.Click, btn189.Click, btn190.Click, btn191.Click, btn192.Click, _
    btn193.Click, btn194.Click, btn195.Click, btn196.Click, btn197.Click

    With DirectCast(sender, Button)


        If txtAdd.Text = ("") Then

        End If
        txtAdd.Text = .Text

        If txtAdd.Text >= 151 Then
            lblCharge.Text = ("10")

        ElseIf txtAdd1.Text = ("") Then

        End If
        txtAdd1.Text = .Text

        If txtAdd1.Text < 151 Then

        End If
        lblCharge.Text = ("12.50")

    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Let me get this straight … you manually put 200 buttons on a form? Oh my god. You must have a lot of free time.

Comment: lol.  I can just imagine the interface :o)

Comment: You are trying to compare a `String` value with an `Int` value. (e.g. `txtAdd.text < 151`).

Comment: All of the buttons are labelled in the syntax btn1 btn2 btn3 etc, how would I make just he number and integer and fix it? :/

Comment: If you need 200 buttons on a form, then something is wrong with your UI and you need to think about alternative ways. For example, a combobox with the possible values.

Comment: It's a theatre booking system and we have to visually display all of the seats etc, it sucks :(

Comment: Well, maybe you should then consider diplaying an image with all the seats and work out a method to detect which seat was clicked by coordinates of the mouse pointer.

Comment: Any idea how I would do that and assign a value to each area?

Comment: @user2083368: Alternatively just programmatically add the buttons and handlers.

Comment: @user2083368: Also, if `txtAdd.Text` *is* `>= 151` then the value will be overwritten by a charge of '12.50' later in the same piece of code you're showing us.

Comment: @user2083368  for such an image you only need 1 `MouseMove` event handler that determines which seat was clicked on the image by reading the pointer's `x` and `y` coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about extracting the number on the button name, you can do it like this:

```
sNum = senderBtn.Name.Substring(3)
```

Or:

```
sNum = senderBtn.Name.Replace("btn","")
```

Or even using `Regex`. There is a lot of ways. And don't forget to convert it to `Integer` with:

- `CInt()`
- `Convert.ToInt32()`
- `Integer.Parse()`
- etc.